# Password History for ASP.net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

One of my requirements is to check the last 5 password history entries over the past year to make sure clients are not reusing passwords.

I've already created a Password entity and Passwords collection on my User entity.

I need to create a custom user manager that inherits from `UserManager<TUser>` and overrides methods that add/update the password to populate the history. I will also have to create a custom password validator that inherits `PasswordValidator<TUser>` and override the `ValidateAsync` method.

How does one go about registering these custom implementations in .Net Core 2.0?   Do you have to replace the `services.AddIdentity` helper with all of the individual dependency injection calls? Or is there a way to override only the `UserManager` and `PasswordValidator` pieces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace the services that get registered by default with the `AddIdentity()` call by simply registering your services on top of them. The dependency injection container will keep *all* registrations around, but when services request an instance, it will only use the latest registration for a type. So you just need to make sure that you register your services in exactly the same way, the original services were registered. So in doubt, [check the implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L59) to see what services get registered how.

In your case, you probably want to do something like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<MyUser, MyRole>();
services.AddScoped<UserManager<MyUser>, CustomUserManager>();
services.AddScoped<IPasswordValidator<MyUser>, CustomPasswordValidator>();
```

Comment: Interesting... When looking at the implementation I noticed they use `services.TryAddTransient`. According to Intellisense, this only registers the service type if it hasn't already been registered. So now I'm wondering if it is best to register it before or after the call to `AddIdentity()`. Will try both and post the results. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, due to the use of `TryAddScoped` and `TryAddTransient`, I was able to add my custom implementations before calling `AddIdentity`.

Comment: That’s great to know! Thanks for reporting back :)

Answer (score 1):

Another idea that works in your case and can work in multiple other cases is to search for a method that will let you add different functionalities along with identity.

For example:

```
  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddUserManager<UserManager>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

for specifying a different `UserManager` implementation.

In your case you can use `AddPasswordValidator` method:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
})
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddPasswordValidator<SameCharacterPasswordValidator<User>>();
```

and Identity framework will do all the DI work for you:

```
 public virtual IdentityBuilder AddPasswordValidator<TUser>() where TUser : class
 {
    return this.AddScoped(typeof (IPasswordValidator<>).MakeGenericType(this.UserType), typeof (TUser));
 }
```